# PHP time not acurate

Tags: php

When run the code below the result is 12:16:35 am when in realty it is 12:31.
does anyone know how to fix this?

Code:

```
        <?php
           date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Amsterdam');
           echo date("h:i:sa");
        ?>
```

Comment: It's 12:31 on your PC I presume. But the code shows the time __on the server__. So you have to set the correct time on the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it doesn't show your timezone `echo date_default_timezone_get();`

Then try setting your timezone using

```
<?php 
date_default_timezone_set('America/Costa_Rica');
echo date("h:i:sa");
?>
```

you can find the string identifier which suits you best on the link below.
http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.america.php

Comment: your php code is on your local system or on a server?

Comment: it is on my localhost. im using xampp as localhost.